# empty data error with ajax xml

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm having a simple php page the echo simple xml data like this

```
<user>
<username>jack</username>
<userage>20</userage>
</user>
<user>
<username>sally</username>
<userage>30</userage>
</user>
<user>
<username>steph</username>
<userage>40</userage>
</user>
```

and using this jquery code to display these information inside a div after clicking a button like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#get").on('click',function(){

            $.get('dataxml.php',function(data){

                var str = '';
                $(data).find('user').each(function(){
                    var uname = ''; var uage = '';
                    $(this).find('username').each(function(){
                        uname = $(this).text();
                    });
                    $(this).find('userage').each(function(){
                        uage = $(this).text();
                    });
                    str += "<div><p class='uname'>"+uname+"</p><p class='uage'>"+uage+"</p></div>";
                });
            console.log(str);

            $("#result").html(str);
        });
    });
});
```

console says 'empty string' but when i view the console data i get this as in the image and the #result div is empty. So what's the error and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
$(data).find('user')
```

it yields nothing because `user` are a root nodes of your XML document (technically the structure is not valid XML).

You can instead go with

```
$(data).each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

directly to iterate over `username` nodes.

The best thing to do however is to wrap entire response with some node so the XML will become:

```
<users>
    <user>
        <username>jack</username>
        <userage>20</userage>
    </user>
    <user>
        <username>sally</username>
        <userage>30</userage>
    </user>
    <user>
        <username>steph</username>
        <userage>40</userage>
    </user>
</users>
```

Then you will be able to use `$(data).find('user')`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/7CquZyDTPFWbROgZWVP1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working and what I did is what I learned from infinite skills course but turned out that it's wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Wrap your XML response with one more root node and you will be able to use `find('user')`.